# how to have cleaner code (when your text is in other languages not English)

Tags: reactjs

I have to use Persian/Farsi (foreign language) in text, title everywhere in my code which makes it messy. I am looking for a way in which I can organize my code so there is no Persian text in it. For example a keyword in English instead of the Persian text and just have the text in a different file.

Comment: what is mean cleaner code?

Comment: For clarification: is the Persian text all user-facing text? For example: `<p className="hello-world">سلام دنیا</p>` or is there Persian in the markup itself?

Comment: You could use some i18n library to separate the message and key. Is it what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Persian text is all in the user-facing text and not in the markup, you can have the Persian in an external JSON document which you link to the appropriate React components.

For example, you might have a JSON document (`page-text.json`) with some Persian text that looks like this:

```
{
    "helloWorld": "سلام دنیا"
}
```

And then a React component with your markup in it where you import that JSON:

```js
// assume some React boilerplate up here
const PAGE_TEXT = require('./page-text.json');
const HelloWorld = () => <span className="hello-world">{PAGE_TEXT.helloWorld}</span>;
```

As Ivanhoe Cheung mentioned in their comment, you can also use an i18n (internationalization) library to possibly make this easier. The one that I have used for React projects with non-English text before is [i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n) on npm. However, this may be more complexity than you need if this project is only going to be in Farsi without the option to use it in other languages -- most of i18n's features are geared towards projects which need to work in multiple languages, for example Farsi and English in the same project.